# Providing an EC private key to certificate for use in HttpClient C#

Tags: c#, ssl

I have an certificate which I can read using the X509Certificate2 class like this:

X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"certificate.pem");

But I also have an **EC** private key. This are it's file contents.

```
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHcCAQEEIKpAuZ/Wwp7FTSCNJ56fFM4Y/rf8ltXp3xnrooPxNc1UoAoGCCqGSM49
AwEHoUQDQgAEqiRaEw3ItPsRAqdDjJCyqxhfm8y3tVrxLBAGhPM0pVhHuqmPoQFA
zR5FA3IJZaWcopieEX5uZ4KMtDhLFu/FHw==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

How do I 'feed' this private key to the certificate and eventually to my **HttpClient** so that it will become usable as a client certificate?

This is the rest of my code:

```cs
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"certificate.pem");
//certificate.PrivateKey = something;
httpClientHandler.ClientCertificates.Clear();
httpClientHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
httpClientHandler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;
httpClientHandler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;

HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
HttpResponseMessage result = httpClient.GetAsync("https://server.cryptomix.com/secure/").Result;
string str = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Comment: @canton how is this related? The OP is already using certificates. The question is about something different

Comment: @canton7 the question is *not* unclear. EC keys exist. [Check this question for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45111422/ec-private-key-to-cngkey-in-c-sharp). They *are* used by certain payment services. They are not certificates

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Combining the certificate and key with openssl, and feeding that into the x509certificate class works:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in certificate.pem -inkey privatekey.pem -out cert-and-key.pfx
```

And then using this to obtain a class with assigned private key:

```cs
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2("cert-and-key.pfx", "password");
```

And then the code in my question works.

Comment: The accepted answer did not work for me. It was giving error: `Could not load file or assembly 'BouncyCastle.Crypto, Version=1.8.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0e99375e54769942' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)`. This works great by converting the PEM file to PFX.

Answer (score 9):

I think I've got it... This uses the BouncyCastle NuGet package.

```
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
using Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Pkcs;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System;
using System.IO;

string pemKey = @"-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHcCAQEEIKpAuZ/Wwp7FTSCNJ56fFM4Y/rf8ltXp3xnrooPxNc1UoAoGCCqGSM49
AwEHoUQDQgAEqiRaEw3ItPsRAqdDjJCyqxhfm8y3tVrxLBAGhPM0pVhHuqmPoQFA
zR5FA3IJZaWcopieEX5uZ4KMtDhLFu/FHw==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----";

string pemCert = @"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----";

var keyPair = (AsymmetricKeyParameter)new PemReader(new StringReader(pemKey)).ReadObject();
var cert = (Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate)new PemReader(new StringReader(pemCert)).ReadObject();

var builder = new Pkcs12StoreBuilder();
builder.SetUseDerEncoding(true);
var store = builder.Build();

var certEntry = new X509CertificateEntry(cert);
store.SetCertificateEntry("", certEntry);
store.SetKeyEntry("", new AsymmetricKeyEntry(keyPair.Private), new[] { certEntry });

byte[] data;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    store.Save(ms, Array.Empty<char>(), new SecureRandom());
    data = ms.ToArray();
}

var x509Cert = new X509Certificate2(data);
```

The trick seems to be to combine the cert and key together into a pkcs12 container, then feed that into `X509Certificate2` in one go.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44770878/5301903) to decrypt an encrypted private key. e.g.: `-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----`

Comment: Your code is generating: "Unable to cast object of type 'Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters' to type 'Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.AsymmetricCipherKeyPair'.". As per the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62580847/6583298, Since you are only using a public key and you don't actually have a pair of keys (public & private) you can't cast it as 'AsymmetricCipherKeyPair' you should cast it as 'AsymmetricKeyParameter'.

Comment: @Mecanik Thanks! It's been 4 years since I wrote this, so maybe something changed in BouncyCastle. Thanks for the edit

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the method X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile.
Here is the link to the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.createfrompemfile?view=net-7.0)!

```
var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();

var cert = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile(certificateFile, privateKeyFile);
httpClientHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);

var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
HttpResponseMessage result = httpClient.GetAsync("https://server.cryptomix.com/secure/").Result;

string str = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

where certificateFile and privateKeyFile are file paths to your PEM files,

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Does this allow for an EC private key?